# Building Android Automotive from source

Tags: android-source, android-auto

### TL;DR

After building Android Automotive from source, how do I

1. Run the car-emulator?
2. "Install" the CarService and related packages onto a device?

### Details

I'm trying to build [Android Automotive](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/) from source. I'm able to successfully build it using the following commands:

`$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-8.0.0_r11
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch car_emu_x86_64-userdebug
$ make -j8 V=1 &>> make.log`

My question is how do I run the emulator? After googling and going through some stackoverflow posts, I came across this:

First, I set an env variable in the command-line (The emulator uses this to determine which emulator to launch)

`export ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=/path/to/build_root`

Next, I created a file `car-emulator.sh` and put this in it (the build was done on an Ubuntu machine)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ANDROID_BUILD_OUT=/path/to/build_root/out
PREBUILT=/path/to/build_root/prebuilts
EMULATOR_OUT=${ANDROID_BUILD_OUT}/target/product/car-x86_64

${PREBUILT}/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator \
    -sysdir ${EMULATOR_OUT} \
    -system ${EMULATOR_OUT}/system.img \
    -ramdisk ${EMULATOR_OUT}/ramdisk.img \
    -data ${EMULATOR_OUT}/userdata.img \
    -kernel ${PREBUILT}/qemu-kernel/x86_64/kernel-qemu \
    -scale 0.7 \
    -memory 512 \
    -partition-size 1024
```

I also tried to download the relevant (darwin-x86_64) files from the build machine to my Mac laptop and tried running there. The emulator starts but crashes immediately with a huge native stack trace.

The next part of my question is how do I install this image on a device?
I see that the CarService.apk has been generated. Is it sufficient to install this APK on a device for it to work? Or should the CarService and related packages be part of a system image that needs to be flashed in its entirety?

Comment: No luck getting this to work so far.  However looking at AOSP commits it looks to me as this is still very much a work in progress. We can hope that Google will put out more documentation when it is ready

Comment: @ curioustechizen ,  "Android automotive"  is it an independent code repository or a part of on and after  "Android – 8.0 Oreo".
If Independent can you please direct me to the proper source code link .
As of now ,it seems to me as a part of "Android – 8.0 Oreo" and further series.

Comment: @Nihar It is not an independent repository. Instead it is part of Android 8 oreo and above. See the tag that I mentioned in my question, and the tag mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50230351/570930

Note that the Automotive code is spread across several packages - the most relevant are packages/services/Car and hardware/libhardware/car

Answer (score 4):

This is how I got it to work on **Android 8.1.0** branch *OPM5.171019.017*:

```sh
$ source ./build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch aosp_car_x86_64-eng
$ emulator
```

Followed by the below output on the terminal:

> emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (2562 MB > 200 MB)
>
> emulator: WARNING: data partition size adjusted to match image file (550 MB > 200 MB)
>
> warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.sse4a [bit 6]
>
> warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.sse4a [bit 6]

And the android emulator display shows up booting android automotive.
I would recommend you try building the engineering version if the above solution does not work in *userdebug* mode.
Please share the stack trace for further analysis.

About the second part of your question. I think you are mixing up android auto with android automotive.

Android Auto is just an app and can be deployed/setup using an APK and some minor tweaking, while Android Automotive is a customized version of android designed specifically for the automotive industry with its own set of system applications. Therefore, it cannot be simply deployed on a device by just installing an APK.

Answer (score 2):

This is my PC env that can run Android Car Emulator
Ubuntu 16， 16G Ram, 1T Disk

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-9.0.0_r39
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch car_emu_x86_64-userdebug
$ make -j8
$ emulator
```

and then Android Emulator boot up just as below.

[Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdnk9.jpg)