# Android AOSP Automotive Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, automotive

I'm trying to build an Emulator for Automotive since Android studio 3.5 is not detecting the system image. I have tried in Android 8 and 9 and downloaded all the tools. How to build the automotive emulator in AOSP?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

You will require Mac or Linux to build the emulator
Perform the steps mentioned in the following site https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing, then follow the steps mentioned in the following site https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading, then execute the following commands

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-9.0.0_r39
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch car_emu_x86_64-userdebug
$ make -j8
$ emulator
```

for reference see the following question on SO [Building Android Automotive from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423114/building-android-automotive-from-source).

Comment: I am still building

Comment: Hi, I managed to build branch android-10.0.0_r2, the emulator works and has car data. But VHAL properties are not visible. https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*GN95R0A6O3UE7eesqUpUrA.png VHAL eg Car properties here. Do you know how to enable these 2 tabs for the emulator?